Update the column joining 2 tables
I have 2 tables, Table 1 is a master which has code and respective plants. Table 2 has some data where I have the same code in Master(table 1) and I have to update the plant column in Table 2 as like plant in table 1 as code as reference. I tried below update statement which is not working. Please help me to update.
UPDATE TABLE_B B
SET B.PLANT = CASE
                  WHEN (B.CODE IN (SELECT CODE  FROM TABLE_A A))
                      THEN A.PLANT 
                      ELSE NULL
              END;

Table 1



code
plant




A001
30009


B001
30018


C001
30006



Table 2



DATE
CODE
PLANT




2024-09-03
A001



2024-09-03
B001



2024-09-03
C001



2024-09-04
A001



2024-09-04
C001



2024-09-05
A001



2024-09-06
B001



2024-09-06
A001



2024-09-06
C001





Wouldn't that be redundant data in table 2? ... The plant reference can be retrieved by joining the two on code.

Plant column in Table 2 is added now and  I have to maintain the Same values from table 1. We can join 2 tables and take plant reference can be retrieved by joining the two on code. I tried which is not working and missing somewhere. Please help me with the query statement for update

@Ambika.. I think it would be simpler to use JOIN or at least the idea of it. I don't use Hana and can't test it, but something like shown in this answer should work. In other RDBMS like SQL Server, that's really trivial, see this db<>fiddle, but in Hana, it seems a litte bit more complicated.
